# Accessing static java methods in Python through jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I am currently trying to access a static class in java, within python. I import as normal, then I try to get the class instance of the java class.

```
from com.exmaple.util import Foo

Foo. __class___.run_static_method()
```

This doesn't seem to work. suggestions? What am i doing wrong.

Comment: In Java, you would do this: `Foo.someStaticMethod()` Does that work for you or doesn't that work with jython?

Comment: Please provide some more detail about what exactly is happening. Check that you are not using same method_name in caller and the called class.http://bugs.jython.org/issue1002

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
Foo.run_static_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you create an instance of the class and just call the method on that.

```
from com.example.util import Foo

foo = Foo()
foo.run_static_method()
```

Assuming just doing `Foo.run_static_method()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this example:

```
Jython 2.5.1 (Release_2_5_1:6813, Sep 26 2009, 13:47:54) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_22
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import java.lang
>>> java.lang.System.getProperty('user.dir')
u'/home/vinay'
```

Note that `getProperty` is a static method of static class `java.lang.System`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this with a class only holding static methods:

```
public class foo {
     public static void bar() {
         ...
     }
}
```

Adding a dummy constructor helped in my case. I guess this is because of pythons nature were classes are actually already objects (there is a [long post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949) about metaclasses giving some details about class understanding in python, its worthy a read eventhough it is a different topic), and jython trying to make the class an object before running the function eventhough it is static. I f this would be true that might be a bug report. (I am testing on jython2.5).

**update**: I don't consider my theroy for thecause to likely since I believe Java has some pure static classes as well. However the solution resolved the issue twice.

**with dummy constructor:**

```
public class foo {

     public foo() {}   //!This dummy constructor did the trick for me

     public static void bar() {
         ...
     }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, too.  There's a gotcha that the other answerers are unaware of.  If the Java *class* doesn't have the keyword `public`, then its static methods will not be available to Jython.  This is confusing because it's independent of whether the methods themselves are public, and other ways of accessing the not-explicitly-public class work, such as instantiation.  In summary, do this:

```
public class foo {
    public static void bar() { ... }
}
```

not this:

```
class foo {
    public static void bar() { ... }
}
```